# Cucumber Test failure with expect false to be truthy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I'm relatively new to using cucumber test and I need help debugging and understanding what I'm doing wrong.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <span class="card-title">Order History</span>
    <% if @previous_orders.empty? %>
      <p>No orders at this time</p>
    <% else %>
      <table class="striped highlight">
        <thead>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </thead>
        <% for order in @previous_orders %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= link_to order.date.strftime("%m/%d/%y"), order_path(order) %></td>
            <td>$<%= order.grand_total %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </table>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My error is this:

```
And I should see "$22.50"              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:88
      Expected false to be truthy. (Minitest::Assertion)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:92:in `/^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/level_2.feature:56:in `And I should see "$22.50"'
```

Please help!

Comment: Try removing the dollar character. Any luck?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks though! I did number_to_currency on my grand_total :)